# Calling Struts2 Namespace from Normal HTML form

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, action

**Exception :**

Description: The requested resource `/Strut2Examples/checkMethods/updateCRUD` is not available. How to call the *namespace* based action from *normal* HTML for with Struts2. It works with Struts2 Forms. Please help me to understand.

**HTML :**

```
    <s:form namespace="/checkMethods" action="executeCRUD" >            
        <s:submit label="execute" value="execute" />
    </s:form>

    <form  name="normalForm" id="normalForm">
    <input type="button" value="update" onclick="submitForm()"/> 
    </form>
```

**Java Script :**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function submitForm()
     {
         var myForm = document.getElementById("normalForm");
         myForm.action="checkMethods/updateCRUD";
         myForm.submit();
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use HTML form tag you should build the URL using the action name and namespace attributes of the `url` tag. For example

```
<form action="<s:url namespace="/checkMethods" action="deleteCRUD"/>" method="POST">
```

The same concern the JavaScript code where you could mix `url` tag. Like this

```
myForm.action='<s:url namespace="/checkMethods" action="deleteCRUD"/>';
```

Actually if you define the action attribute of the form you don't need to construct the URL in the event handler function. Just do `submit()` .

You should take `url` tag seriously, because for example you have constructed URL in the action attribute that lacks context path and slash and errors like that you did can't count.

Comment: Thanks for reply,How to use the namespace of the Struts2 without sturts2 tags like <s:url.......... ?

Comment: You can get a namespace from the  `ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getNamespace()`

Comment: So you say i can't achive this without struts2 tags in form ! Becuase using ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getNamespace() can get but can't set in form.

Comment: In the form or script you have to set `action` attribute, because you are not using struts `form` tag you can use struts `url` tag. If you don't want to use both tags then you have to build the url manually. Take care of supplying correct URLs to Struts that is to be able to retrieve an action configuration that corresponds to action mapping. Otherwise you will get 404 error code.